# Add row between specific rows in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

i copy data from one datasheet to another. At the moment i'm inserting every new row in the target sheet above the last inserted line with

```
datasheet.insertRowAfter(1);
```

Every row has a timestamp in the following format:

> 25.05.2021 23:30:00

The timestamp is set automatically when data get copied and is rounded to the last .30 time.
If i forget to copy the data sometimes, gaps are created. Therefore i want to copy missing data manually.
I created a Boolean and a time in my Sourcesheet
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8afow.png

Now i want to copy my Data to the targetsheet inbetween the existing timestamps. For example my 8.30 timestamp from the screenshot above has to be set in this row:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N8LW.png

I want to "loop" through the Timestamp column and find the correct row for the manual time and create a new row there and copy my data.
Creating rows and copying data is not my problem, just finding the correct row between two dates.
It is important to me to take both date and time into account.

I don't know how to solve this and haven't found anything online. Can anyone help out?

EDIT:
current code to copy from sheet to sheet

```
function Parsetracking() {
  var spa=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inputsheet = spa.getSheetByName("Parse Output");
  var datasheet= spa.getSheetByName("Tracker");
  var parsesheet = spa.getSheetByName("Parse Input");

  var nowdate = new Date();
  var nowdateeurope = convertTZ(nowdate, "Europe/Berlin");
  var lastdate = datasheet.getRange("L2").getDisplayValues();
  var lasttime = datasheet.getRange("N2").getDisplayValues();
  
  var checkdate = joinDateAndTime(lastdate,lasttime)
  var diff = nowdateeurope - checkdate;
  if (parsesheet.getRange("j2").isChecked() === true) {
    //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Under Construction.');

    if (parsesheet.getRange("i2").getValue() < datasheet.getRange("k2").getValue()) {
      Logger.log('smaller')
    }
    else {
      Logger.log('bigger');
    }
    return;
  } 
  else {
    if(diff >= 3600001){
      datasheet.insertRowAfter(1);
      datasheet.clear;
      var datecell = datasheet.getRange("L2");
      var timecell = datasheet.getRange("M2");
      var roundedtimecell = datasheet.getRange("n2");
      inputsheet.getRange("A2:J2").copyTo(datasheet.getRange("A2:J2"),{contentsOnly:true});
      inputsheet.getRange("A3:J3").copyTo(datasheet.getRange("o2:W2"),{contentsOnly:true});
      datecell.setValue(nowdate).setNumberFormat("dd:mm:yyyy");;
      timecell.setValue(nowdate).setNumberFormat("hh:mm:ss");

      var gmt = new Date();
      gmt.setHours(nowdate.getUTCHours()+2);
      var hours = gmt.getHours();
      var minutes = nowdate.getUTCMinutes();
      var newtime = hours + ':' + minutes;
      console.log(newtime);
      var roundedtime = RoundTimestamp(newtime);
      console.log(roundedtime);
      roundedtimecell.setValue(roundedtime);
      datasheet.getRange('K3').autoFill(datasheet.getRange('K2:K3'),SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES)

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You say `I want to "loop" through the Timestamp column and find the correct row for the manual time and create a new row there and copy my data.` how does one determine the correct row?

Comment: Do you have a code you are working on? Please consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on so that your issue can be more clearly understood.

Comment: @Cooper thats is basically my question. how can i find the correct row  within one specific column? Forget the date and times, maybe its easier to understand with numeric values.
if my column has the following values


5
4
2
1
0
and i want to insert a 3 between 2 and 4. how can i find the correct position within the column?

Comment: @Iamblichus i provided my current code but i doubt it'll help to understand my question :) thanks four your effort tho

Comment: So you have a source timestamp and a series of timestamps in a column, and you want to find the row index where the source timestamp would belong (later date than the previous row, and earlier than the next one). Is that the case? I assume you already know how to compare these timestamps, right?

Comment: @Iamblichus exactly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your timestamps are sorted and have the same format it can be done this way:

```js
const timestamps = [
    "25.05.2021 23:20:00",
    "25.05.2021 23:30:00",
    "25.05.2021 23:40:00",
    "25.05.2021 23:50:00"
];

const missed_timestamp = "25.05.2021 23:35:00";

function DMY_to_YMD(dd_mm_yyyy) {
    return dd_mm_yyyy.replace(/(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)/, "$3$2$1");
}

const missed_YMD = DMY_to_YMD(missed_timestamp);

var index = 0

for (var time of timestamps) {
    if (missed_YMD < DMY_to_YMD(time)) break;
    index++;
}

timestamps.splice(index, 0, missed_timestamp);

console.log(timestamps);
```

Output:

```
[
  "25.05.2021 23:20:00",
  "25.05.2021 23:30:00",
  "25.05.2021 23:35:00", <-- here is the missed timestamp
  "25.05.2021 23:40:00",
  "25.05.2021 23:50:00"
]
```

If you have a really huge list of timestamps it makes sense to try to implement a binary search.

To convert simply 2D-arrays into 1D-arrays and vice versa:

```js
console.log([ [1], [2], [3] ].map(x => x[0])) // [ 1, 2, 3 ]

console.log([ 1, 2, 3 ].map(x => [x])) // [ [1], [2], [3] ]
```

**Update**

For small arrays it can be done even simpler:

```js
const timestamps = [
    "25.05.2021 23:20:00",
    "25.05.2021 23:30:00",
    "25.05.2021 23:40:00",
    "25.05.2021 23:50:00"
];

const missed_timestamp = "25.05.2021 23:35:00";

const DMY_to_YMD = (dd_mm_yyyy) => 
    dd_mm_yyyy.replace(/(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)/, "$3$2$1");

const t     = DMY_to_YMD(missed_timestamp);
const arr   = timestamps.map(x => DMY_to_YMD(x));
const index = arr.concat([t]).sort().indexOf(t);

timestamps.splice(index, 0, missed_timestamp);

console.log(timestamps); // the same output as above
```

Comment: the timestamp list has about 1000-2000 rows. thx for your suggestion, i'll try to implement something like this later :)

Comment: If you happen to like the fancy cryptic functional style you can remove the loop and get the `index` this way: `const index = timestamps.map(t => DMY_to_YMD(t)).filter(t => t < missed_YMD).length;`

Comment: Works so far, thanks! I only have the problem that the replace function throws an error. (replace is not a function) But I think I can handle that one.

Comment: The error could happen if the value is not a string. As a work around you can try to convert the value into string: `dd_mm_yyyy.toString().replace(/(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)/, "$3$2$1");`

Comment: yep,. already tried that. just got another error with tostring is not a function. but i got it running now, with formatting the timestamp string. my current problem is: my timestamps are in a specific column. my way to set the cólumn values to an array is: const timestamps = [ datasheet.getRange("K2:K").getValues() ];. But this creates a multidimensional array which i'm not ready to handle yet haha. an easy for loop seems not enough

Comment: If your 2D-array has just one column it can be converted into 1D-aray via `flat()` method. This way: `const timestamps = [ datasheet.getRange("K2:K").getValues().flat() ];` It does this: `[ [1], [2], [3] ]` --> `[ 1, 2, 3 ]`. And you can do backward operation `two_D_array = [1,2,3].map(x => [x])`

Comment: nice! now i got it running! thank you so much :) i had to `flat()` two times: `const timestamps = [ datasheet.getRange("K2:K").getValues().flat() ];
    const flattimestamps = timestamps.flat();`

Comment: You can use `flat()` just once if you get rid of the square brackets: `const timestamps =  datasheet.getRange("K2:K").getValues().flat()`. Square brackets mean to convert the value into array. You don't need this actually in this case